# How to test if member is integral in concept?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to define a concept that tests if a particular member variable (in the example, 'x'), exists and is an integral type. I'm getting stumped though, since `v.x` returns an `int&` and thus the `std::integral` check fails. How can I make this work?

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept isIntegralX = requires(T v) {
    {v.x} -> std::integral;
};

template <typename T>
requires isIntegralX<T>
void bar(const T& base)
{
}

class Foo
{
public:
    int x{0};

    void baz()
    {
        bar<Foo>(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
note: the expression 'is_integral_v<_Tp> [with _Tp = int&]' evaluated to 'false'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the concept as:

```
template <typename T>
concept isIntegralX = std::is_integral_v<decltype(T::x)>;
```

`decltype(T::x)` yields the exact type `int` here.

For multiple members you can

```
template <typename T>
concept isIntegralXandY = std::is_integral_v<decltype(T::x)> && std::is_integral_v<decltype(T::y)>;
```

Comment: I reduced the example to just a single variable, but I would like the concept to check multiple (`v.x`, `v.y`, etc). Is there a similar way to accomplish that?

Comment: @Archduke In that case, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69794701/1348273).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting stumped though, since v.x returns an int& and thus the std::integral check fails. How can I make this work?

You can try doing an explicit cast to turn the lvalue expression into an rvalue:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept isIntegralX = requires(T v) {
    { decltype(v.x)(v.x) } -> std::integral;
    // Or you could write: `{ static_cast<decltype(v.x)>(v.x) } -> std::integral;`
    // ...
};
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To reply to OP's further asked question posted as a comment under [songyuanyao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69793872/1348273). See here for details about [std::conjunction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction). In general, you would want to check [<type_traits>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) for type-related metaprogramming utilities provided by C++.

```
template <typename T>
concept is_x_and_y_integral = std::conjunction_v<
  std::is_integral<decltype(T::x)>,
  std::is_integral<decltype(T::y)>
>;
```

Comment: [This doesn't compile.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jTdnW9qPa) Is there a reason to use `std::conjunction` instead of `&&`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Fixed a small issue. See it live [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q156ZXMPS1efHt2J). Yes, you are right. `std::conjunction` is somewhat overkill in this specific case. In general, however, it's more versatile and powerful. E.g., you can use it to query the first type that fails (evaluates to false).